# Remove multiple data depending on viewport flag in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map where I'm checking which zoom and translation the viewport has, so I can show the information. In my case circles are pooping up over the world/over germany/over syria.

[image: Firt interaction]

[image: germany 2nd]

[image: syria 3rd]

The main part looks like this where I'm checking which part of the map is seen and how the zoom level is

```
var minZoomTresholdCountry = 15
var minXG = -462,
    maxXG = -552
    minYG = -29,
    maxYG = -98;

var minXS = -647,
    maxXS = -544,
    minYS = -104,
    maxYS = -164;

var zoomCheck = 0, //zoomcheck which zoom level? Which country is focussed //0 = WORLD 1 = GER 2 = SYR
    filterCheck = 1; //how is POI diplayed? Per day or over TIME? 0 per day 1 over Time

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .html(function(d) { return d.properties.description })
  .offset([0, 3]);
svg.call(tip)

function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  sites.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  var translate = zoom.translate();
  var translateX = translate[0]/zoom.scale();
  var translateY = translate[1]/zoom.scale();
  // console.log(translate[0]/zoom.scale() + "   " + translate[1]/zoom.scale());
  // console.log(zoom.scale());

  if (zoom.scale()<minZoomTresholdCountry) {
    //console.log("WELT");
    zoomCheck = 0;
    // if( siteDataG ){
    //   siteDateG.remove();
    // }
    // if(siteDataS){
    //   siteDataS.remove();
    // }
  }
  else if(zoom.scale() >= minZoomTresholdCountry
    && translateX< minXG && translateX > maxXG
    && translateY<minYG && translateY>maxYG){
      //console.log("DE");
      zoomCheck = 1;
  }
  else if(zoom.scale() >= minZoomTresholdCountry
    && translateX> minXS && translateX < maxXS
    && translateY<minYS && translateY>maxYS){
      //console.log("SYR");
      zoomCheck = 2;
  }
  else{
    zoomCheck = 0;
  }
  //console.log(zoomCheck)



  if(zoomCheck == 0){
    showSmth();
  }
}

d3.json("data/vorfaelle.json", function(error, data){
    window.site_dataG = data;
});
d3.json("data/syria_sorted.json", function(error, data){
    window.site_dataS = data;
});

d3.json("data/newtest.json", function(error, data){
    window.site_dataW = data;
});

d3.json("data/isil.en.json", function(error, data){
    window.site_dataB = data;
});

dpG = d3.time.format("%d.%m.%Y").parse;
dpS = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

//
// var minDate = dpG("01.01.2015");
// var maxDate = dpG("31.12.2015");
var minDate = moment.utc("2015-01-01").toDate();
var maxDate = moment.utc("2016-01-01").toDate();
var secondsInDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; //DAYS

var slider = d3.slider()
    .axis(true).min(minDate).max(maxDate).step(secondsInDay)
    .on("slide", function(evt, value) {

    temp = moment(value,"x").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    tempVal = moment(temp).unix()*1000;


      if( filterCheck == 0 ){

        if( zoomCheck == 0 ){

          newDataW = site_dataW.features.filter(function(d){

            dataDate = moment(d.properties.date).utc().unix()*1000;
            // console.log("dataDate " + new Date(dataDate));
            // console.log("slidDate " + new Date(value));
            //console.log("-- " + moment(dataDate).toDate());


            if (dataDate == tempVal) {
              //console.log("Sucess");
              //console.log(moment(dataDate).toDate());
              return moment(dataDate).toDate();
            }
          });
          showWorldSite(newDataW)

        }

        else if( zoomCheck == 1 ){

          newDataG = site_dataG.features.filter(function(d){
            dataDate = moment(d.properties.date).utc().unix()*1000;
            //console.log(value);
            if (dataDate == tempVal) {
              //console.log("Sucess")
              return moment(dataDate).toDate();
            }
          })
          showGermanSite(newDataG);
        }

        else if( zoomCheck == 2 ){

          newDataS = site_dataS.features.filter(function(d){
            dataDate = d.properties.Date;
            if (dataDate == temp) {
              return moment(dataDate).toDate()
            }
          });

          showSyrianSite(newDataS);
        }

      }
//================================================================================================
//================================================================================================
//================================================================================================

      else if( filterCheck == 1 ) {
      //
        if( zoomCheck == 0 ){

          newDataW = site_dataW.features.filter(function(d){

            dataDate = moment(d.properties.date).utc().unix()*1000;

              //console.log(new Date(dataDate) < new Date(value));
              return moment(dataDate).toDate() < moment(tempVal).toDate() ;



          });
          //console.log(newDataW.length);
          showWorldSite(newDataW)

        }
      //
        else if( zoomCheck == 1 ){

          newDataG = site_dataG.features.filter(function(d){
            dataDate = moment(d.properties.date).utc().unix()*1000;
            //console.log(moment(dataDate).toDate());
            return moment(dataDate).toDate() < moment(tempVal).toDate() ;
          })
          // console.log(newDataG.length);
          // console.log(new Date(value));
          showGermanSite(newDataG);
        }

        else if( zoomCheck == 2 ){

          newDataS = site_dataS.features.filter(function(d){
            // dataDate = moment(d.properties.Date).utc().unix()*1000;
            dataDate = d.properties.Date;
            // return dpS(d.properties.Date) < new Date(value);
            // return moment(dataDate).toDate() < moment(tempVal).toDate() ;
            // return moment(dataDate).isBefore(tempVal);
            return new Date(dataDate) < new Date(temp);
          });

          showSyrianSite(newDataS);
        }

      }





    });

d3.select('#slider3').call(slider);

function showWorldSite(data){

  var siteDataW = sites.selectAll(".siteW")
      .data(data);


  siteDataW
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "siteW")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[1]
      })
      .attr("r", 6)
      .transition().duration(70)
      .attr("r", 4);

    siteDataW.exit()//remove the selection which are to be removed from dataset
        .transition().duration(10)
        .attr("r",0)
        .remove();
}


function showGermanSite(data){


  var sitedataG = sites.selectAll(".siteG")
      .data(data);
  sitedataG
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "siteG")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[1]
      })
      .on("click", tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
      .attr("r", 1.25)
      .transition().duration(70)
      .attr("r", 0.25);
    sitedataG.exit()
      //.transition().duration(200)
        .attr("r",0)
        .remove();

}

function showSyrianSite(data){
  var radScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
      return d.properties.Value }))
    .range([0.1,.5]);
  var siteDataS = sites.selectAll(".siteS")
      .data(data);
  siteDataS
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "siteS")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[1]
      })
      .attr("r", function(d){
        return 1.75 * radScale(d.properties.Value)
      })
      .transition().duration(70)
      .attr("r", function(d){
        return radScale(d.properties.Value)
      });

    siteDataS.exit()
        //.transition().duration(10)
        .attr("r",0)
        .remove();


}

function showSmth(){
  console.log("Here will be something soon");
}
```

Is there an effective way to remove data if it is not used (not in viewport/ not in the zoom view) in my case? I could remove the circles when the case of zoomCheck equals 0 etc is triggered when I do something like this in the zoom function:

```
var sitedataG, sitedataS, sitedataW;

if (zoom.scale()<minZoomTresholdCountry) {
  zoomCheck = 0;
  sitedataG.remove();
  sitedataS.remove();
}
else if(zoom.scale() >= minZoomTresholdCountry
  && translateX< minXG && translateX > maxXG
  && translateY<minYG && translateY>maxYG){
    zoomCheck = 1;
    sitedataW.remove();
    sitedataS.remove();
}
else if(zoom.scale() >= minZoomTresholdCountry
  && translateX> minXS && translateX < maxXS
  && translateY<minYS && translateY>maxYS){
    //console.log("SYR");
    zoomCheck = 2;
    sitedataW.remove();
    sitedataG.remove();
}
```

But this is no proper solution and it is not really wroking either (error because of course not always siteData is created so it can't be removed)

If you want to take a look at my full code, feel free to use [this](https://github.com/RitterLean/remove-data-byzoom)

Comment: why do u want to hide points not in the viewport...what are you goin to gain from that...i think the best is to show all the filtered points and not make any complications...just a suggestion.

Comment: fair point. did not think of that